# Handsontable : datas aren't returned to the php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handsontable

I'm french so excuse me for my english :)
I checked a lot of topics. Some seems to be the same problem but it still doesn't work. I'm a beginner in javascript too.

So, here is my code :
`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var container = document.getElementById('Grille_competences');

var headerRenderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value,
cellProperties) {
Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
td.style.textAlign = 'center';
td.style.backgroundColor = '#B0C4DE';
};

//Initialisation des données de la grille.
var data = [["Compétences","Description","Code",""],
        ["", "", "",""],
        ["","", "",""],
        ["","", "",""],
        ["","", "",""],
        ["","", "",""]];

//Création de la grille
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
data: data,
height: 800,
width: 1183,
colWidths: [35,200,25,80],
manualRowResize: true,
colHeaders: true,
rowHeaders: true,
mergeCells: true,
stretchH: 'all',
columnSorting: true,
contextMenu: true,    
contextMenuCopyPaste: {
  swfPath: './zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf'
},


//Fonctionnalités lors d'un clic droit dans la grille.

 contextMenu: {    

   items: {
    "row_above": {
        name: 'Insérer ligne au dessus',
      disabled: function () {            
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "row_below": {
        name: 'Insérer ligne en dessous',
        disabled: function() {            
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
    }
  },
    "hsep1": "---------",
    "col_left": {
        name: 'Insérer colonne à gauche',
        disabled: function () {
          return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
        }
    },
    "col_right": {
        name: 'Insérer colonne à droite',
        disabled: function() {
          return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
        }
    },
    "hsep2": "---------",
    "remove_row": {
      name: 'Supprimer la ligne',
      disabled: function () {
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },

    "remove_col": {
      name: 'Supprimer la colonne',
      disabled: function () {
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "hsep3": "---------",
    "copy": {
      name:'Copier',
      disabled: function () {
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "paste": {
      name: 'Coller',
      disabled: function(){
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "hsep4": "---------",
    "undo": {
      name:'Précédent',
      disabled: function(){
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "redo": {
      name: 'Suivant',
      disabled: function(){
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "hsep5": "---------",
    "make_read_only": {
      name: 'Lecture seule',
      disabled: function() {
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "alignment": {
      name: 'Alignement du texte',
      disabled: function () {
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;        
      }          
    },
    "mergeCells": {
      name: 'Fusionner les cellules',
      disabled: function () {
        return hot.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },


    },
},


//Entetes de la grille en lecture seule. 
cells: function(row, col, prop) {
var cellProperties = {};
if(row===0){
cellProperties.renderer = headerRenderer;
}   
if(row === 0 && col <3){
       cellProperties.readOnly = true;
       }
return cellProperties;
}
});

//Lors d'un clic sur le bouton valider, transmission des données de la grille.


});

document.getElementById('save').onclick=function () {

            $.ajax({
            url: "testGetData.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'data':hot.getData()}, //retourne les données des cellules
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },



        });
            document.location.href='testGetData.php';
    };
```

`

And here is the code for testGetData.php :

```
<?php

foreach($_GET['data'] as $value)
    echo $value;
?>
```

The problem is that testGetData.php seems to not receive the $_GET['data'].
I tried many differents things I've seen on forums or the Handsontable's doc.
I thought the cause was the scope, but I did the same as the examples (At least i believe ^^).

Can you help me please ? I don't understand what's wrong. I need a fresh look at my code.

Comment: Have you tested whether `hot.getData()` actually returns any data? There should be an array of arrays. I have used handsontables but connected it using jQuery and then used the added jQuery method `handsontable()` on the container where the data is presented for editing. In your case this would be something like: `$(container).handsontable('getData')` or `$('#Grille_competences'.handsontable('getData')`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know how to test what hot.getData() returns. I tested `data: {'data':$(container).handsontable('getData')},` and the href doesn't work anymore...

Comment: you could open a JavaScript console while the page is open for editing on your browser (on Firefox just press <shift><control>k ) and then you can enter `$('#Grille_competences').handsontable('getData')` on the command line at the bottom. The one with the `>>` prompt. This command should be returning the mentioned array.

Comment: okay thx, with hot.getData(), a array of array is returned. But It's still considered as undefined in the testGetData.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was **not related with hansontable** but with the way you sent the data using the jQuery ajax method: You **specified a `dataType: 'json'`** but the processing .php file **returned a plain text** format.

You should change two things, first in your .html-file:

Replace the `document.getElementById('save').onclick=function () { ... }` function with:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "testGetData.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {data: hot.getData() }, 
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (retobj) { alert(JSON.stringify(retobj)); }
  });  
}
```

(What is the point of including the jQuery library if you don't use it ...) The stuff inside is more or less unchanged, although I changed the `success()` function a litle bit. It will reformat the returned JavaScript object `retobj` back into a JSON format again, so you will be able to see all its elements. The clever thing about the jQuery `ajax()`method with `dataType:'json'` is, that the data returned from the .php script will appear in the `success()` function already as a JavaScript object without you having to do anything!

And secondly - **the most important thing** - in your .php file:

In order to supply the `success()` function with the desired `json` formatted string the `testGetData.php` script needs to **return some data in a `json` format**. The easiest way of doing this is to use the **php function `json_encode()`**:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Assuming that `hot.getData()` delivered an array like this one:

```
data= [[0,1,2,3],
       [100,101,102,103],
       [200,201,202,203]];
```

Then the alert function will return the following string after the `#save`-button was clicked (I tested it - without handsontable though):

```
{"data":[["0","1","2","3"],["100","101","102","103"],["200","201","202","203"]]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !I didn't understand very well the meaning of json

Comment: And *I did not know* that you can actually *send any data object* (in this case the array of arrays) to the URL *using the* `GET` *method*. I always assumed this was only possible using the `POST` method! ;-)